# Error when trying to deploy Stripe on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, stripe-payments

I'm trying to hook up Stripe Checkout for a Rails app, but when I deploy it (both locally and on Heroku), I get:

```
NoMethodError in Builder#index.......undefined method `stripe' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007ff403128b18>
```

It says this is the code with the problem (second line is the one throwing the error):

```
 <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
   data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
   data-description="A month's subscription"
   data-amount="500"></script>
<% end %>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Silly question... have you got the stripe gem in your Gemfile? have you run `bundle install` ? if you run `rails console` and type `Rails.configuration.stripe` does it also explode? Finally... the code you have copied above... where (what file and line) is it located?

Comment: I'd just like to check, you're using a script tag in the code you posted, so it should be in some html, it seems to end with an erb end block so I just want to check that you're not trying to do anything other than display it in an html page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `secrets.yml`, they're exposed under `Rails.application.secrets`, **not** `Rails.configuration`:

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
   data-key="<%= Rails.application.secrets.stripe['publishable_key'] %>"
   data-description="A month's subscription"
   data-amount="500">
</script>
```

If you're not using `secrets.yml`, your configuration isn't getting loaded properly. Check that you're actually defining `stripe` configuration data on `Rails.config` and that it's where you expect it to be.